Induced morphism in Čech cohomology
Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces. If $F$ is a sheaf on $Y$ we denote by $f^{-1}F$ the pullback sheaf on $X$. I know that there is a morphism induced between the sheaf cohomology groups
$$
H^q(Y,F)\rightarrow H^q(X,f^{-1}F).
$$
My question is if there is such a morphism between the Čech cohomology groups
$$
\check{H}^q(Y,F)\rightarrow \check{H}^q(X,f^{-1}F).
$$
When the spaces are Hausdorff and paracompact Čech cohomology agrees with sheaf cohomology so the morphism exists. In Eilenberg-Steenrod's Algebraic Topology the morphism is constructed for constant sheaves. But I could not find any reference for the general case.

I think it's somewhere in the stacks project. I do not have Eilenberg--Steenrod at hand, but does their proof really rely on constancy?

Yes, there is. The construction is straightforward, though I will not do the cumbersome detail checks. If $\mathfrak{U}=(U_i)_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of $Y$, we obtain an open cover $f^{\ast}\mathfrak{U}=(f^{-1}U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $X$. The unit of the pushforward-pullback adjunction is a sheaf morphism $F\rightarrow f_{\ast}f^{-1}F$, which yields maps $F(U)\rightarrow(f^{-1}F)(f^{-1}U)$ compatible with restriction. These in turn yield a map between the respective Čech cochain complexes, which induces a pullback map $\smash{\check H}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},F)\rightarrow\smash{\check H}^\bullet(f^{-1}\mathfrak{U},f^{-1}F)$. Now, a refinement $\mathfrak{U}\rightarrow\mathfrak{V}$ induces a refinement $f^{\ast}\mathfrak{U}\rightarrow f^{\ast}\mathfrak{V}$. You can check the pullback map just constructed is compatible with these refinements, so we ultimately obtain a map
$$\smash{\check H}^\bullet(X,F)=\mathrm{colim}_{\mathfrak{U}}\smash{\check H}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},F)\rightarrow \smash{\check H}^\bullet(Y,f^{-1}F)=\mathrm{colim}_{\mathfrak{V}}\smash{\check H}^\bullet(\mathfrak{V},f^{-1}F).$$
